# how do i get music album picture and music url together using a loop from firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

i am making a music streaming website, my firebase storage folder looks like song>happy>music folder containing music and music album picture and i want to load all albums in a loop to display on my website, how should i do that? This is my code but the console throws error forEach I dont even know if im doing it right. Can someone please help me?

```
const listRef = ref(storage, 'songs/happy/');

listAll(listRef).then((res) => {

    res.prefixes.forEach((folderRef) => {
  
    res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
      itemRef.getDownloadURL().then(function (link){console.log(link)
    });
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  }); });
```

Comment: What error do you get? Also: did you step through the code in a debugger already?

Comment: i actually dont know how to get the folders of songs into an array from the firebase storage. Each song has a folder. Inside the folder there is the audio file and the cover photo of the music. Is there any way you could help me with getting all the song urls into an array and display them on the website?

Comment: In that case it sounds like you'll need to call `listAll` on the prefixes (just a fancy name for "folders") again, as mentioned in the [documentation sample](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files#list_all_files) as `// You may call listAll() recursively on them.`